# How can I morph between 2D sprites?

Tags: animation

A friend and I are writing a topdown RPG called NecroMonster. In the game when you defeat an enemy you can take its shape (basically morph into it) and we don't know how to make this look right.

How can I create a morph animation between several 2D sprite sets that are relatively simple and will look the part?

Comment: Think powerpoint slide transitions: fade to black, blur, spin...

Comment: yeah that could be a good idea

Comment: This question can't be answered with right answer. It's asking for opinions. That is not what QA is all about ( with very few exceptions ).

Comment: youre right i didnt really think about it before its more of a wiki  Q

Comment: I editted it to try and fit back into our usual technical Q and A format. If you could follow this up with some example code that you have in place or explain your existing framework for how you handle animation of your characters we could help you a little more and it would also tend towards a better question (by providing the opportunity for a more definitive answer).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If its  a 2D RPG then you are surprisingly more flexible than its 3D counterpart. If you are working with just simple sprites then you are only limited by your desire and skill to animate it.

There won't be any right answer here as this is more a graphical design choice than a technical question or limitation - due to that I would recommend making this a wiki entry for "ideas for morphing" or similar.

My idea would be to play on your games title and theme: **Necro**-Monster.

Seeing as "necro" signifies the dead and corpses you could have the character sink into the floor or crouch into a black, death like mass (giving you a set starting point for all charater transformations to keep things simple). After a short pause they "uncrouch" into the monster *shape*. The monster form would then shake off the black-death mass material or it would simply fade or slide off depending on your desired graphical complexity.

Comment: youre right its sort of a broad question theres no right or wrong answer i dont have alot of flexibility since we are using pygame (a pretty limited 2d library) but those are some good ideas

Comment: When you are using a 2D sprite map it really is only limited to your sprite animations (and maybe sprite map file size requirements) otherwise in a 3d version you have to do matrix transformations for groups of vectors to take a humans shoulder and morph it into a monsters shoulder. Imagine this process for each section of body and you can see how much time you are saving with 2D!

Comment: thats very true its alot easier in 2d